# Open a VMware Server 2.0 console with just one click

Tags: remote, vmware-vsphere, console

Currently you have to login to the VMware Infrastructure Web Access GUI, select the VM, and then open the console.

Is it possible to open a console with one click or one command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YEP!

- First open the web console
- In the *Inventory*, select the VM you wish to create a shortcut for
- In the *commands* list, select **Generate Virtual Machine Shortcut**
- ZING!

Answer (score 2):

There is one interesting trick you can use if you just want to see the console.  If you have vmware player installed you can run a command like this.  Vmware player will attach to the console.  If you have a specific server that you frequently access build a shortcut/alias/script.

```
vmplayer -h vmwareserver.example.tld -u "username"
```

Also see this [page](http://communities.vmware.com/docs/DOC-8840) for some more tips.